# Apache Solr: I have run this command in Cygwin Terminal. ./nutch crawl urls -dir newCrawl -solr http://localhost:8939/solr/ -depth 10 -topN 10

Tags: java, indexing, solr, cygwin, nutch

SolrIndexer: starting at 2015-10-15 10:13:00
Adding 90 documents:

```
java.io.IOException: Job failed!
SolrDeleteDuplicates: starting at 2015-10-15 10:13:11
SolrDeleteDuplicates: Solr url: http://localhost:8939/solr/
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.solr.SolrDeleteDuplicates$SolrInputFormat.getSplits(SolrDeleteDuplicates.java:200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeOldSplits(JobClient.java:810)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:781)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:730)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1249)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.solr.SolrDeleteDuplicates.dedup(SolrDeleteDuplicates.java:373)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.solr.SolrDeleteDuplicates.dedup(SolrDeleteDuplicates.java:353)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl.run(Crawl.java:153)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl.main(Crawl.java:55)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:478)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:244)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.QueryRequest.process(QueryRequest.java:89)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.query(SolrServer.java:118)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.solr.SolrDeleteDuplicates$SolrInputFormat.getSplits(SolrDeleteDuplicates.java:198)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:286)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:80)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:122)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:422)
        ... 13 more
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Your solr url is not valid. You need to write the core as well. By default the core is collection1. Therefore, in your case the url is http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1

Answer (score 0):

Solr doesn't seem to be running - Connection refused indicates that something is unable to contact whatever it should contact. Your configuration is probably broken, or you haven't started Solr or you're running on a different port.